# Trial Periods / Expiry of VSTO VB Projects?

Tags: excel, vsto

Is it possible to set trial periods/expiration date for an VSTO VB project made for an Excel workbook at a document level?

We are building a small management app and would like to set up a subscription service to use the "app". Almost like a licensing feature, where after X days or on THIS DATE - just stop all functionality and request the user to renew their license. The latter part is not the issue, of actually getting a the subscription renewed but stopping all functionality at the date is our main goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: make a check on click or load event?